# Combine text as part of shape outline photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

Hello can someone tell me how id get the effect in the image in photoshop or a link me to a tutorial on how.

Pardon my crude drawing skills
Thank you[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Draw your star (perhaps using the Custom Shape Tool):

[image: Built-in star]

- Type out your word using the font of your choosing (try to pick one that will nicely 'flow' into and out of the star)... Make the stroke of your star close to the same thickness as the text
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to activate Free Transform, rotate your star so that the part you want to add your text to is horizontal (take note of rotation value so you can reverse the change later):

[image: Straight up]

- Line up your text where you want it to be on the star... If necessary you can go to Type > Convert to Shape and then use the Direct Selection Tool (<kbd>A</kbd> key, white arrow) to align individual letters up/down
- Making sure the text layer is highlighted in the Layers Panel, drag out a couple of guides and snap them to either side of the text:

[image: Applying guides]

- Hit the <kbd>M</kbd> key to activate the Rectangular Marquee Tool and drag a box around your text, snapping to the guides, then go to Select > Modify > Contract and choose the appropriate value for your artwork:

[image: Making a rectangular selection]

- Go to View > Clear Guides
- Highlight the star layer in the Layers Panel and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+click on the 'Add layer mask' button:

[image: Masking operations: Apply mask]

- Highlight the star and the text layers in the Layers Panel, right-click on them and choose 'Convert to Smart Object'
- Now you can <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to scale and rotate them together as desired...

Final result:

[image: STARMAN!]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

That is done with the "Type on a path" tool. This tool can be used on any shape that has a stroke.

I drew a star, selected the tool then clicked the edge of the star and started typing.

There are many options and settings besides the usual illustrator type tools.

[image]

To join the shape path to the word first expand the shape and text (convert to outlines). Arrange the word and shape how you want then hit Pathfinder>Divide.

Delete the parts that are not needed, selected whats left and use Pathfinder>Join to put them back together.

See how the shape and the S are one shape now?

[image]

Comment: Thanks i know about path tool i was trying to actually manipulate the star into the shape of the writing